# dataGridView won't reflect updated dataset

Tags: c#, datagridview, visual-studio-2013, dataset

On my main form I have the following method:

```
private void updateSet()
{
    dsManager.fillPeriodSet();

    dataGridView1.DataSource = null;

    dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dsManager.mainSet;

    dataGridView1.DataMember = "nice_table";
}
```

This method is called from the constructor when the form initializes and again after dataset is updated with an additional "period". It works perfectly that first time when the form loads, the functionality to alter the dataset works as well and I can confirm that the new value has been added successfully via the inspector window.

When it's called the second time, nothing happens even though the dataset has been correctly updated.  If I close the form and re-run, it will again display correctly including the newly added "period".

I know there are lots of other similar questions on this and other forums and I have tried out at least 10 of them. Nothing that seems to be working for others is working here.

Has anyone had any experience with this issue in the past?

Comment: what's ur project type?? web or windows??

Comment: After an additional week of trying various things I can get the datagrid to remain the same, clear completely, and clear and show a blank row.  The only thing that it won't do is show the updated datatable.  I have also tried using binding sources as well but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after about a week or so of playing around with every possible variation of my code, I finally got everything to work when I made the following change:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = itemSet1;
dataGridView1.DataMember = "items_formatted";
```

to

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = itemSet1.Tables["items_formatted"];
//dataGridView1.DataMember = "items_formatted";
```

Apparently something was going on with the `DataMember` attribute that caused the DataGridView to not refresh.  Even when I cleared it explicitly (`dataGridView1.DataMember = null;`) and it showed as cleared in the Locals window, it was still having some sort of residual effect that made it impossible to reload the dataset.

Very frustrating and if anyone knows why this is I would love to know. Otherwise I hope that this question/answer at least helps someone else in the same position.

UPDATE:

For additional reference, the code in my orginal question was updated from:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = dsManager.mainSet;

dataGridView1.DataMember = "nice_table";
```

to:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = dsManager.mainSet.Tables["nice_table"];
```

and now that works as well. No additional clear/updating/restructuring code was needed for any of my forms.

Answer (score 0):

When the application is active and has multiple forms, the active form is the form with the input focus. A form that is not visible cannot be the active form. The simplest way to activate a visible form is to click it or use an appropriate keyboard combination.

in c# windowsApplication u have an event called [Form_Activate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activated(v=vs.110).aspx)

u can handel this event and run ur code when this event Occurred.

```
private void Form1_Activated(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        //your code :)
    }
```

Comment: thanks @farid but how does this help my datagrid refresh problem? The code is running correctly and without error, it's just not DOING anything.

Comment: @BenW301 when program returned to main form , will occur Form_activated , u can re call ur code in this event , just call ur updateSet() method :)

Comment: That was my point, i don't have any problems calling the method again, that part works and i can confirm that it's hitting every line of the method a second time, it just doesn't actually change the datagrid to represent the new dataset even though it reloaded the new dataset.

Comment: Perhaps I just do not understand what you mean :) u can refresh ur dataset and assign it to grid again

Comment: check this links :
[link] (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365160(v=sql.100).aspx)
[link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221369/when-adding-a-column-more-to-a-db-table-how-do-you-get-your-datagridview-to-sho)

Comment: i run the method once....it populates my datagrid from the dataset.  I run it a second time....it populates my datagrid from the previous version of the dataset which has since been updated. It's somehow either ignoring the dataset or caching the old version and not updating it.  Because i know the code works and i know the dataset was updated correctly, the datagrid is just not reflecting that update.  and the links didn't help, sorry.

Comment: how do you save ur changes on dataset ? what changes ?? how occur that changes ??

Comment: im sorry, that's not really relevant to the question.  I think i am going to wait for someone else to answer. thanks for your input though!

Comment: I was going to help you, dear friend :)
I'm sorry I could not help you in this case, good luck